# Custom values in Google Cloud Logging / Metrics

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

Can Google Cloud Logging / Metrics support custom values? E.g. can a log line contain a key-value pair, such as its value is included in metrics *as value*, as opposed to having to print the key multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not supported. Logs-based metrics are "gauge" metrics (counters) that increment once each time a log entry matches the filter.